# Where is the cache folder of an "Designed for iPad" App running on MacOS

Tags: ios, macos, apple-m1

We are distributing an iOS app to the Mac App Store via the "Designed for iPad" mechanism. I am now wondering where the documents / cache / ... folders are. I can't find anything in `~/Library/Application Support` neither in `~/Library/Caches`.

Where are the applications files saved?

Comment: What folder exactly are you looking for? "Where are the applications files saved?" They are saved where you save them. Where exactly are you saving them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean the `NSDocumentDirectory`? I think it is under the `~/Library/Containers/<bundle id>/Data/Documents`.